# Парсинг Python beautifulsoup

Tags: python

Здравствуйте хотел парсить типа онлайн дневник (похожее в dnevnik.ru). Я получая html страницу все ок. Проблема в том что как сохранить оценки типа так:
Недавно начал писать код в python
И есть ли возможность получить данные из атрибутов

**Вот html:**

```
    <tr>
        <td class="tac">1</td>
        <td class="s2">
            <strong class="u">Алгебра</strong>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:left;" class="tac">
            <span class="mark mG analytics-app-popup-mark " title="Ответ на уроке, 20 сентября 2022, 1 урок"
                data-id="1996445545229819889" data-work_id="1993798702914166938" data-num="0">
                5
            </span>
            <span class="mark mG analytics-app-popup-mark " title="Ответ на уроке, 4 октября 2022, 1 урок"
                data-id="2003631351933528193" data-work_id="2000100824391686735" data-num="0">
                5
            </span>
            <span class="mark mG analytics-app-popup-mark " title="Ответ на уроке, 12 октября 2022, 5 урок"
                data-id="2003631549502031168" data-work_id="2001604694305506763" data-num="0">
                5
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tac">1</td>
        <td class="s2">
            <strong class="u">Алгебра</strong>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:left;" class="tac">
            <span class="mark mG analytics-app-popup-mark " title="Ответ на уроке, 20 сентября 2022, 1 урок"
                data-id="1996445545229819889" data-work_id="1993798702914166938" data-num="0">
                5
            </span>
            <span class="mark mG analytics-app-popup-mark " title="Ответ на уроке, 4 октября 2022, 1 урок"
                data-id="2003631351933528193" data-work_id="2000100824391686735" data-num="0">
                5
            </span>
            <span class="mark mG analytics-app-popup-mark " title="Ответ на уроке, 12 октября 2022, 5 урок"
                data-id="2003631549502031168" data-work_id="2001604694305506763" data-num="0">
                5
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tac">1</td>
        <td class="s2">
            <strong class="u">Алгебра</strong>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:left;" class="tac">
            <span class="mark mG analytics-app-popup-mark " title="Ответ на уроке, 20 сентября 2022, 1 урок"
                data-id="1996445545229819889" data-work_id="1993798702914166938" data-num="0">
                5
            </span>
            <span class="mark mG analytics-app-popup-mark " title="Ответ на уроке, 4 октября 2022, 1 урок"
                data-id="2003631351933528193" data-work_id="2000100824391686735" data-num="0">
                5
            </span>
            <span class="mark mG analytics-app-popup-mark " title="Ответ на уроке, 12 октября 2022, 5 урок"
                data-id="2003631549502031168" data-work_id="2001604694305506763" data-num="0">
                5
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**Вот что я хочу получить:**

````
        {
            subject: 'физика',
            grades: [
                { mark: "5" },
                { mark: "5" },
            ]
        },
        {
            subject: 'алгебра',
            grades: [
                { mark: "5" },
                { mark: "4" },
                { mark: "5" },
            ]
        },
        {
            subject: 'география',
            grades: [
                { mark: "5" },
                { mark: "5" },
                { mark: "5" },
            ]
        },
    ]```
````

Comment: по моему я где-то видел уже этот вопрос...

Comment: @Acinit оказывается я неправильно дал вопрос из-за этого повторно дал

Comment: Да, есть возможность. Бери справку или примеры использования и смотри как. PS. Минус за заголовок.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Словари во множества не входят, только ключи, по этому кортеж словарей.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = ''' </body>   <tr>
        <td class="tac">1</td>
        <td class="s2">
            <strong class="u">Алгебра</strong>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:left;" class="tac">
            <span class="mark mG analytics-app-popup-mark " title="Ответ на уроке, 20 сентября 2022, 1 урок"
                data-id="1996445545229819889" data-work_id="1993798702914166938" data-num="0">
                5
            </span>
            <span class="mark mG analytics-app-popup-mark " title="Ответ на уроке, 4 октября 2022, 1 урок"
                data-id="2003631351933528193" data-work_id="2000100824391686735" data-num="0">
                5
            </span>
            <span class="mark mG analytics-app-popup-mark " title="Ответ на уроке, 12 октября 2022, 5 урок"
                data-id="2003631549502031168" data-work_id="2001604694305506763" data-num="0">
                5
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tac">1</td>
        <td class="s2">
            <strong class="u">Алгебра</strong>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:left;" class="tac">
            <span class="mark mG analytics-app-popup-mark " title="Ответ на уроке, 20 сентября 2022, 1 урок"
                data-id="1996445545229819889" data-work_id="1993798702914166938" data-num="0">
                5
            </span>
            <span class="mark mG analytics-app-popup-mark " title="Ответ на уроке, 4 октября 2022, 1 урок"
                data-id="2003631351933528193" data-work_id="2000100824391686735" data-num="0">
                5
            </span>
            <span class="mark mG analytics-app-popup-mark " title="Ответ на уроке, 12 октября 2022, 5 урок"
                data-id="2003631549502031168" data-work_id="2001604694305506763" data-num="0">
                5
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tac">1</td>
        <td class="s2">
            <strong class="u">Алгебра</strong>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:left;" class="tac">
            <span class="mark mG analytics-app-popup-mark " title="Ответ на уроке, 20 сентября 2022, 1 урок"
                data-id="1996445545229819889" data-work_id="1993798702914166938" data-num="0">
                5
            </span>
            <span class="mark mG analytics-app-popup-mark " title="Ответ на уроке, 4 октября 2022, 1 урок"
                data-id="2003631351933528193" data-work_id="2000100824391686735" data-num="0">
                4
            </span>
            <span class="mark mG analytics-app-popup-mark " title="Ответ на уроке, 12 октября 2022, 5 урок"
                data-id="2003631549502031168" data-work_id="2001604694305506763" data-num="0">
                3
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</body>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")
tr = soup.find_all('tr')
a = ()
for el in tr:
    d = {'subject': el.find('strong').text}
    grades = []
    for ee in el.find_all('span'):
        grades.append({'mark': ee.text.strip()})
    a += (d, {'grades': grades},)
print(a)
```

---

```
({'subject': 'Алгебра'}, {'grades': [{'mark': '5'}, {'mark': '5'}, {'mark': '5'}]},
 {'subject': 'Алгебра'}, {'grades': [{'mark': '5'}, {'mark': '5'}, {'mark': '5'}]},
 {'subject': 'Алгебра'}, {'grades': [{'mark': '5'}, {'mark': '4'}, {'mark': '3'}]})
```